# When building the ACL2 books, how do I get rid of an error about "Magic number..."

Tags: perl, acl2

When building the books for ACL2, I get the following error.  How do I get rid of it?

```
Magic number checking on storable file failed at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/Storable/_retrieve.al) line 380, at /<elided>/sw/acl2/books/build/certlib.pl line 1850
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the files `cert-pl-cache.tmp` and `build/Makefile-cache` if they exist.

It's symptomatic of an incompatability between the version of Perl used to write the cache, and the version currently being used to read the cache.